# how to show day and hour from timestamp in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

When I use diffForHumans it show 1 hour ago.
When it cross 24 hour and show 1 day ago then 2 day, 3 day, 1 week, 2 week.
But i want to show 1 day and 1/2/3/4 hour ago. then 2 day 1/2/3/4 hour ago.

I have been using laravel 5.7

Answer (score 1):

Use `->diffForHumans(['parts' => 2])` (or more parts if you want minutes, seconds, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$diffInDays = $user->created_at->diffInDays();
$showDiff = $user->created_at->diffForHumans();
if($diffInDays > 0) $showDiff .= ', '.$user->created_at->addDays($diffInDays)->diffInHours().' Hours';
echo $showDiff;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `longAbsoluteDiffForHumans()` or `longRelativeDiffForHumans()`, as an example given below :

```
$prev = Carbon::create(2018, 2, 26, 4, 29, 43);
$now = Carbon::now();
$diff = $prev->longAbsoluteDiffForHumans($now, 6);

return $diff; // 2 years 4 months 2 weeks 2 days 11 hours 5 minutes
```

See the official documentation  [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff)

Comment: It show an error Method longAbsoluteDiffForHumans does not exist in blade file

Comment: @MizanurRahman in the blade you need to do like `{{ $data->created_at->longAbsoluteDiffForHumans(6) }}` use `longAbsoluteDiffForHumans(6)` instead of `diffForHumans()`

Comment: Call to a member function longAbsoluteDiffForHumans() on string

Comment: $diff = \Carbon\Carbon::create(2018, 2, 26, 4, 29, 43);
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
$res = $diff->longAbsoluteresForHumans($now, 6);
return $res;

Comment: I tried
`$submitdate = date('Y-m-d, H:m:s', strtotime($submit->created_at));
$diff = \Carbon\Carbon::create($submitdate);
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
$res = $diff->longAbsoluteresForHumans($now, 6);
return $res;`

Comment: you cannot return on blade, use `@php $diff = \Carbon\Carbon::create(2018, 2, 26, 4, 29, 43); $now = \Carbon\Carbon::now(); @endphp {{ $diff->longAbsoluteresForHumans($now, 6) }}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217684/discussion-between-mizanur-rahman-and-sta).

Answer (score 0):

It is work with day count.

`@php($diffInDays = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->created_at)->diffInDays())`

`@php($showDiff = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->created_at)->diffForHumans())`

`@if($diffInDays > 0)`

`@php($showDiff .= ', '.\Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->created_at)->addDays($diffInDays)->diffInHours().' Hours')`

`@endif`

`{{$showDiff}}`

Answer (score 0):

- 

my answer is not better than the above answers, but below code worded for me as i customized the time column in the database.

```
 date('H', strtotime($time_column))
```

it's a php function, and you can change the format I mean the **'H'** the first argument in **date()** function to the format that best suit your app.

- another solution is using **Carbon**  laravel time class like below code examples
  `Carbon::parse($time_column)->hour`
  `Carbon::parse($time_column)->day`

this depends the value of the $time_column